# Usar uma CSS diferente em cada view

Tags: css, html5, mvc

Estou desenvolvendo um site usando o padrão MVC, gostaria de saber se é possível usar uma CSS diferente em cada view. Se sim, como?

Comment: Qual framework está usando?

Comment: Não estou usando nenhum framework, apenas criei os controllers, views e models com php e html5, faço algumas chamadas usando autoload e chamo as páginas com funções php dentro de uma página chamada template

Comment: Essa página "template" usa um css, mas as páginas que eu vou chamar precisariam de um outro css, só que elas automaticamente carregam o css da página template

Comment: É só você adicionar o css de cada view dentro dela mesma, assim como faria com arquivos .js ...

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 700px)" href="arquivo.css">
```

Não sei bem se é isso o que está procurando, mas dessa forma o CSS só carrega se a largura cumprir o requisito determinado.